# Serial Communication Between 3 Arduinos Doesn't Work (Daisy-Chain)

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, uart

In my project, I have to send a string from one arduino to a second arduino, and make it send the same string to a third arduino. I used UART and SoftwareSerial library, and connected the arduinos like that:

**In all the arduinos:**
Pin 10 - RX port, pin 11 - TX port
[image]
Arduino 1 pin 11    ---->  Arduino 2 pin 10
Arduino 2 pin 11    ---->  Arduino 3 pin 10
Arduino 3             ---->  PC (by hardware Serial)

**By theory**, Arduino 1 sends string "CA" to arduino 2, which resends that same string to arduino 3, that prints it back on Serial.

**The problem** is that I get the string "C�" instead of "CA" (that weird "C�" is equal to "067 255" on ASCII).
Does anyone knows why it happens? Maybe there's something wrong with my code?

Here's the code for all the three Arduinos:

*Arduino No. 1:*

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define ADDR "CA"
SoftwareSerial tiny(10, 11); //TBD

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //debug only
  tiny.begin(9600);
  delay(2000);

  tiny.write(ADDR);
}

void loop() {
  //nothing here
}
```

*Arduino No. 2:*

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial tiny(10, 11); //TBD
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //debug only
  tiny.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  if(tiny.available() > 0) {
    tiny.write(tiny.read());
  }
}
```

*Arduino No. 3:*

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial tiny(10, 11); //TBD
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //debug only
  tiny.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  if(tiny.available() > 0) {
    Serial.write(tiny.read());
  }
}
```

Any idea on what went wrong?

Comment: Where are your ground connections? I don't see them there.

Comment: Where is it being modified / becoming corrupt ?  Have you printed to debug serial on Arduino 2 to see if it is receiving corrupt data, or if the data is being corrupted on the 2-> leg ?  Also have you swapped them around (Arduino 2 becomes Arduino 3 etc) ?

Comment: @Majenko They are all connected to the PC, so their grounds are connected (nevertheless, I tried to connect their grounds together and it didn't help).

Comment: @KennetRunner It is being corrupted when it gets to Arduino 2 (gives same results). I tried to swap arduino 2 and 3 but it didn't help.

Comment: Connecting the grounds through the USB is not adequate. You need a direct connection between all the boards' grounds.

Comment: SoftwareSerial is appallingly bad. It barely works at the best of times. Try sending 'C' then delaying, then sending 'A'.

Comment: @Ido Daniel - I'd also remove Arduino 3 from the picture until you get 1 -> 2 working correctly, then introduce it back in...

Comment: @KennetRunner Actually, given that Arduino 2 is merely a proxy, I'd remove Arduino 2 until 1 -> 3 directly works correctly...

Comment: @John Burger Given thatArduino 2 is where the first evidence of corruption occurs I'd start there. Either way will work though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arduino #2 should have two SoftwareSerial instances, one to listen to Arduino #1 and another one to talk to Arduino #3:

```
// In Arduino #2
SoftwareSerial tiny1(10, 11); // Listen to Arduino #1 on pin 10
SoftwareSerial tiny2(8, 9);   // Talk to Arduino #3 on pin 9
```

You may not need to wire unused signals (11 and 8).

There is an example here : https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/TwoPortReceive

Note that what you are trying to do is a bus. Serial in Arduino is RS232 based and that is not a bus but a [point to point protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-point_(telecommunications)). You should consider using I²C or SPI.